# Casting in PowerShell. Weird syntax

Tags: powershell, casting, powershell-2.0

Reading XML from a file into a variable can be done like this:

```
[xml]$x = Get-Content myxml.xml
```

But why not:

```
$x = [xml]Get-Content myxml.xml
```

Which gives:

```
Unexpected token 'Get-Content' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:20
+ $x=[xml]get-content <<<<  myxml.xml
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (get-content:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

That is, why is the cast operation done on the left-hand side of the equals sign? Typically in programming languages the casting is done on the right-hand side like (say) in Java:

```
a = (String)myobject;
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
$x = [xml](Get-Content myxml.xml)
```

Comment: Thanks ! Anybody know why these brackets are needed ?

Comment: Because `get-content myxml.xml` is an expression; `(get-content myxml.xml)` is an object. You need to have an object to begin with to cast it to something else!

Comment: To add to this a little, the parentheses around the cmdlet forces the expression to resolve.  Then, the resolved expression, which is now an object, is passed into the cast operator.

Answer (score 8):

In PowerShell everything is an object. That includes the [cmdlets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell#Cmdlets). Casting is the process of converting one object type into another.

What this means for casting is that, like in math, you can add in unnecessary brackets to help you clarify for yourself what exactly is happening. In math, `1 + 2 + 3` can become `((1 + 2) + 3)` without changing its meaning.

For PowerShell the casting is performed on the next object (to the right), so `$x = [xml] get-content myxml.xml` becomes `$x = ([xml] (get-content)) myxml.xml`. This shows that you are trying to cast the *cmdlet* into an `xml` object, which is not allowed.

Clearly this is not what you are trying to do, so you must *first execute* the cmdlet *and then* cast, AKA `$x = [xml] (get-content myxml.xml)`. The other way to do it, `[xml] $x = get-content myxml.xml`, is declaring the variable to be of the type `xml` so that whatever gets assigned to it (AKA the entire right-hand side of the equal sign) will be cast to `xml`.